# Python Numpy: int arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Please help me to get out of this error, maybe, it's duplicate but I could not set it for my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

df = pd.read_csv('DATA.txt',delimiter=',')
df.head() 
X= df.COL1,df.COL2
Y=df.COL3
print(X)
print(Y)
cv = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=10, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)
    
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
print(X_train)
print(Y_train)
```

ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-8c160cb8bf67> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

dataset

```
9.999999,0.1,1
94.9999,0.1,1
89.9999,0.2,0
99.9999,0.3,0
```

Comment: Can you show all the print statements along with the already provided stack trace.?

Comment: What do you think `X= df.COL1,df.COL2` does?

Comment: can you please share sample data from the `DATA.txt`

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I have shared samples.

Comment: @JoeFerndz shared

Comment: For line 1: `9.999999,0.1,1`, `COL1 = 9.999999`, `COL2 = 0.1` and `COL3 = 1` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes exactly

Comment: When you do X = df.COL1, df.COL2, if you are expecting value of only one row to be stored, you are incorrect. You will get a Series. You need to manage it like as such

Comment: @mujjiga can you please help me

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you want to print each row ?

Comment: no, I need to separate X_train, Y_train after k fold successfully, after that I will give it to the classifier. @JoeFerndz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to select your `X` columns slightly differently, e.g.

```py
X = df[['COL1', 'COL2']]
```

Comment: now getting this : KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
this code is not working

Comment: Use `df.iloc[index]` instead. Either that, or switch to only using numpy arrays, e.g. `X = df[['COL1', 'COL2']].values` and `X = df['COL3'].values`.